Asian movie with a serial killer who wears a partial toupee/wig to cover a head injury inflicted by his mother when he was a child
I've been looking for this movie for a long time, but I've always failed to recall the title. Maybe you all can help. Here's what I remember:

It's an Asian movie with Asian actors (maybe Korean, Japanese, or Chinese).
The story is about a police detective hunting a serial killer who murders young girls.
At one point in the story, the serial killer dates the detective's daughter.
At the end of the movie, there's a brutal fight between the detective and the serial killer.
At the end of the movie, it is revealed that the serial killer wears a (partial) toupee/wig to cover a serious head injury. The injury was inflicted on him by his mother when he was a child. It is hinted that this is probably the cause of his hate for women.
(I'm not 100% sure about this.) At some point, the killer lives in the house of a priest. The killer was the priest's handyman/gardener or a similar job. Then the killer killed the priest and took the house.
I don't remember the year, but it's not a very old movie, surely after the 2000s.
The genre is thriller/action. It is realistic; there are no supernatural elements.

I checked and ruled out Bloody Reunion.

Are we sure it’s a wig? Could it be a bunny mask (in which case it’s Bloody Reunion)?

@jsm It was a wig. I checked and it is not Bloody Reunion.
